# Authentication for @JmsListener using Spring 4.2 annotations and ActiveMQ

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

Trying to implement a non-XML JMS listener using Spring 4 and ActiveMQ. My issue is that I keep getting the following error with my client:

```
Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'topic.FromJndiProperties' [...] 
Cause: The JMS connection has failed: Force close due to SecurityException on connect.
Cause: User name [null] or password is invalid.
```

So the connection to the destination is being made with username and password null. I think I may have not setup the destinationResolver correctly but I am stuck working out how to resolve this. Can anyone help me fix this?

My AppConfig:

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Autowired
private BeanFactory springContextBeanFactory;  

@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory myListenerContainerFactory() throws NamingException {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, env.getProperty("java.naming.factory.initial"));
    props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, env.getProperty("java.naming.provider.url"));
    props.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, env.getProperty("java.naming.security.principal"));
    props.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, env.getProperty("java.naming.security.credentials"));

    Context jndiContext = new InitialContext(props);;
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");

    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setDestinationResolver(new BeanFactoryDestinationResolver(springContextBeanFactory));
    factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    return factory;
}
```

The listener:

```
@JmsListener(containerFactory = "myListenerContainerFactory", destination = "topic.FromJndiProperties")
public void receiveMessage(String message) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Received <" + message + ">");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ConnectionFactory`, `TopicConnectionFactory` and `QueueConnectionFactory` all have two ways of creating a connection (eg `ConnectionFactory.createConnection()` and `ConnectionFactory.createConnection(username, password)`.

It seems that the `@JmsListener` annotation always creates a connection without passing the credentials via the zero args methods.

I used spring's [UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/connection/UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.html) to wrap my ConnectionFactory for use with `@JmsListener` so that it passes the credentials when creating connections

Answer (score 1):

If you have not changed any features on the broker end , try the below

```
props.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"admin"
props.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "admin");
```

also in your jndi.properties you can add the properties userName=admin and password=admin instead

Comment: Hi Sundar. Thanks for the advice. These values are already being set though. I think there is something odd in how the destination/session is being created.