# Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination Cause: Authentication failed

Tags: spring-boot, jms

When I'm trying to listen through command line it works fine, but using Spring Boot it throws below error:

```
ERROR [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] (DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1) Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'wfQueue' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=44, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: authentication failed
javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: authentication failed
```

This is my app class

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.source.lbm"})
public class EMSConsumerApp {

    public static main(String[] args){
        run(EMSConsumerApp.class, args);         
    }
}
```

This class configures definitions for JMS consumer

```java
@EnableJMS
@EnableTransactionManagement
public abstract class SubscriberConfiguration {
    private final String url;
    private final String clientId;
    private final String username;
    private final String password;

    public SubscriberConfiguration(String url, String clientId, String username, String password) {
        this.url = url;
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jsmListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory containerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        containerFactory.setconnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        containerFactory.setPubSubDomain(true);
        containerFactory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
        containerFactory.setSessionTransacted(true);
        containerFactory.setAutoStartup(true);
    
        return containerFactory;
    }
        
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() throws JMSException{
        TibjmsXATopicConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new TibjmsXATopicConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setServerUrl(url);
        connectionFactory.setClientId(clientId);
        connectionFactory.setUserName(username);
        connectionFactory.setUserPassword(password);
        return connectionFactory;        
    }
        
}
```

This sets configs for a subscriber

```java
@Configuration
public class LbmSubConfiguration extends SubscriberConfiguration {

    public LbmSubConfiguration(
        @Value("${ems.lbm.sub.url}") String emsUrl;
        @Value("${ems.lbm.sub.clientId}") String subClientId;
        @Value("${ems.lbm.sub.username}") String subUsername;
        @Value("${ems.lbm.sub.password}") String subPasword) {
    super(emsUrl,subClientId,subUsername,subPasword);
    }
}
```

This class listenes to ems and consumes messages

```java
@Component
public class LbmEventConsumer {
    @JmsListener(destination = "${ems.lbm.sub.destination}", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void onMessage(BytesMessage message){
      System.out.println("Message " + message);
    }
}
```

Since these credentials work fine on command line there shouldn't be an issue with credentials. Possibly it's because I'm missing some configs (not sure though). Can you please help me figure out what's wrong with this?

Comment: You don't set the credentials on the jsmListenerContainerFactory

Comment: But I've used TibjmsXATopicConnectionFactory, where I do set the credentials.

Comment: But you use the other connection factory

Comment: I want to use TibjmsXATopicConnectionFactory as it supports URLs, credentials and transactions. As JmsListener calls createConnection() rather than createConnection(String username, String password). Can you please guide me how can I incorporate both of them. As much I understand, you're redirecting me to this approach - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631411/authentication-for-jmslistener-using-spring-4-2-annotations-and-activemq

Comment: Your `jsmListenerContainerFactory` method is returning the variable `connectionFactory` which is a `ConnectionFactory` object. However, the method should return a `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` object (i.e. the `containerFactory` variable). I don't see how this code would even compile.

Comment: Justin, that was just a typo. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work fine, I missed to add SubscriberConfiguration's package in scanBasePackage config.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `@JmsListener`

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${ems.lbm.sub.destination}", 
             containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
```

There you have set "jmsListenerContainerFactory" change it to "jmsConnectionFactory"

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${ems.lbm.sub.destination}", 
             containerFactory = "jmsConnectionFactory")
```